# Google says Mail app is insecure

Tags: applications, release-loki

I've been trying to log in the Mail app with my Gmail account, however I always get a "wrong email or password" message, even though I was sure I had it correct all of the times. I received an email from Google some minutes ago saying that someone tried to log in using an app that has known security problems or is out of date.

Just made a fresh install of Loki.

How do I deal with this situation?

A screenshot of the email:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I always get a "wrong email or password" message

If you are using 2-Step verification then you need to create a password specifically for Mail app. It will work fine. Additionally, if you are using Google App (for business, etc. and not the @gmail account) then again you need to follow specific setup instruction.

I have been using both the gmail (and google business) account without encountering the email you have mentioned. I suspect this might have to do multiple login failures. But that's just a rough guess.

Anyhow, there's a workaround to get the less secure app working. Follow [this link (Google Support)](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en).